# document.ready jquery not working when one html is loaded in div of another

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, html

I load an html page with associated jquery and ajax calls in a div of another document. However, the $document.ready of the html page being loaded does not work.

I use the following syntax for loading the html page in the div of another.

```
$('#LeaveReq').click(function(){
   $('#Showpages').load("leaveapp.html");
});
```

where Showpages is an empty div defined as

```
<div id="Showpages" style = "float:left; width: 85%; background: white;">
<p> this is a placeholder
</div>
```

The page being loaded is as follows

```
<script>

// standard functions for processing forms

function sendval(){
var thisform = document.getElementById("leaveapp");
var tosubmit = validateForm();

if(tosubmit){
   showprog();
   curruser = localStorage.getItem("username");
   curremail = localStorage.getItem("usermail")
   supmail = localStorage.getItem("supmail")

   // write json to submit the leaveform and update values in database
   var myData = [];
   myData.push({'EmpName' : curruser});
   for(var i=0; i<thisform.elements.length; i++)
   {
        myData.push({
        thisform.elements[i].name: thisform.elements[0].value
    });
   }
   myData.push({'UsrMail' : curremail});
   myData.push({'SupMail' : supmail});
   myData.push({'Status' : 'Submit'});

   var myjson = JSON.stringify(myData);

    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "submitleave.php",
    data: {"points": myjson}
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        if(msg == "Success"){
            showcomp();
        else {
            alert("Could not sumbit - try again");
            window.open("index.html","_self");
        }
    });
} else
{
   alert("Please enter valid values before submitting the form");
}
}

function showprog(){
$('#forminput').hide();
$('#formsubmit').show();   
}

function showcomp(){
   $('#formsubmit').hide();
   $('#formsuccess').show();   
}

function onsuccess(retval){
   showcomp();
}

function validateForm(){
var $list = $("#leaveapp :input[type='text']");
var formstatus = true;
$list.each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == null | $(this).val() == ""){
        formstatus = false;
    }
})
return formstatus;
}

$('document').ready(function(){
   $('#formsubmit').hide();
   $('#formsuccess').hide();
   logged_user = localStorage.getItem("username");
});

</script>

<div id='forminput'>

<form id="leaveapp">

<label><?=logged_user?></label>
<p> Leave Type : <select name = "leavetype" id = "leavetype">
                 <option value="Annual Leave">Annual Leave</option>
                 <option value="Casual Leave">Casual Leave</option>
                 <option value="Sick Leave">Sick Leave</option>
                 <option value="Hajj Leave">Hajj Leave</option>
                 <option value="Unpaid Leave">Unpaid Leave</option>
                 </select> </p><br>
<p> Start Date : <input required readonly="true" type="text" name="StartDate" id="txtFromDate" /> </p><br>
<p> End Date :   <input required readonly="true" type="text" name="EndDate" id="txtToDate" /> </p><br>
<p> Contact Number : <input required pattern="[0-9()]{5,15}" type="text" name="Contactnum" id="contactnum" /> </p><br>
<p><input type="text" id = "Comments" name="Comments" value="Comments" /></p> <br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick=sendval()>

</form>
</div>

<script>
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        minDate: "-5D",
        maxDate: "+120D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });

</script>

<script>

$("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+180D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    });

</script>

<script>

$('#leaveapp').on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (code  == 13) {               
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});

</script>

<div id ='formsubmit'>
   <label> "Submission in progress - do not close the window </label>
</div>

<div id = "formsuccess">
<label> Form submitted successfully. Thank you </label>
</div>
```

None of the jquery features of the loaded html function - i.e. date picker does not work, etc.

Please can you tell me what mistake am I making.

I had loaded a similar page but that was working but it was not complicated with a date picker or any validations.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

The reason `$(document).ready` doesn't trigger after you load your html file is because the `$().load` function executes an asynchronous request. Your page doesn't wait for a response before it finishes rendering the page. The ready event will likely have fired before the leaveapp file finishes loading. There are two things you can do to solve this:

**1. Move the ready code until a on-success callback in your load request**

```
$('#LeaveReq').click(function(){
   $('#Showpages').load("leaveapp.html", function() {
        $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate:"+180D",
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function(selected) {
                $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
            }
        });

        $('#leaveapp').on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
          var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
          if (code  == 13) {               
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }
        });
   });
});
```

**2. Make your load request synchronous**

Instead of using `.load`, you could use `$.ajax()` and specify `{async: false}` to get the html file. This is slower and more unwieldy than the first solution.

Comment: the first example did not work. I am not sure how to make an ajax call to load the page in a specific div. I do not want to load the page to use the full window.

Answer (score 2):

You used single quotes for `$('document').ready(function(){` so it is not working as you expected . Try to remove single quotes code should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      // your code here
});
```

Comment: still not working sir. date picker does not show and neither does it allow any input,

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready` is an event that fires when the `document` object is ready and after it does not fires anymore, even if the content of the page changes.

You should re-bind all the event handlers manually using the `success` property of you ajax call or better using event delegation.